# How to stop sending telemetry from a specific function in Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

In my Function Application (v2) I have a function *probe* that is used to test the health of my application and is called every few seconds. I would like to stop logging anything from that specific function to Application Insights.

The function *probe* looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

using MyApp.Api.Hello;

namespace MyApp.Api
{
    public static class HealthFunctions
    {        
        [FunctionName("probe")]
        public static IActionResult Probe(
            [HttpTriggerAttribute(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequest request,
            ILogger logger)
        {
            return new OkResult();
        }
    }
}
```

And host.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "http": {
            "routePrefix": ""
        }
    },
    "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
            "Function.probe": "Error",
            "default": "Trace"
        }
    }
}
```

However I am still seeing the telemetry in Application Insights sent by calling /probe:

[image: Application Insights Screenshot]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have mutiple functions in a function app?

Comment: Yes, probe is one of many functions in the Function Application.

Comment: Hi, as you say, you want to stop logging this function to application insights. But please notice that for a function app, logging is configured in the host.json file on local. And on portal it is configured in application settings. So if you want to stop specfic function logging to application insights, others functions under the same function app will be affected.

Comment: @BowmanZhu AFAIK host.json allows per function settings.

Comment: Hi, are you sure host.json allows per function settings? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json As the doc has says, host.json defines the global configuration options and will affect all functions in a function app. If you know how to define each function in the host.json file, it is similar on the portal.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The link you posted says so, under “logging”.

Comment: Well, what you've done is to disable logs from ILogger within your function. This wont stop the other telemetry data like Request, and traces from the Function App itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 12/09:**

Yes, your comment is correct, there is still some messages about it can be logged into application insights. But any messages logged by `log.LogInformation()` method and should not be written into application insights.

And I find another way can avoid it, you can specify the loglevel for all other function apps; but not for the function app you don't want to log to application insights, do not specify loglevel for it. Then you can specify the **default** as **None**, which can completely avoid this function app to log into application insights.

Here is an example:

I have 3 function apps, and I don't want the function named **HttpTrigger1** to log into application insights. So in host.json, I specify the **loglevel** to **Trace** for the other 2 function apps: **BlobTrigger1** and **QueueTrigger1**. And set the **default** as **None**.

The host.json at my side:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": ""
    }
  },
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Function.BlobTrigger1": "Trace",
      "Function.QueueTrigger1": "Trace",
      "default": "None"
    }
  }
}
```

The screenshot:

[image]

It works as expected, no logs from "HttpTrigger1" are written into Application Insights.

---

For disable logging to application insights from a specific azure function, in the host.json, you can specify logLevel as **None** for that azure function(in your case, it's **probe**). Sample host.json looks like below:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "http": {
            "routePrefix": ""
        }
    },
    "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
            "Function.probe": "None",
            "default": "Trace"
        }
    }
}
```

Then only the function named **"probe"** cannot send data to application insights.

And here is one thing you should note, in the specified azure function -> Monitor, there is a empty log created(see screenshot below), this "empty log" means that no logs are written into application insights(You can just write a query in application insights to confirm this. I tested it with log query, no logs are shown in application insights for that specified azure function).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with None (and also changed the case of the function name to Probe and host.json to Function.Probe. I get the same "No results"  in the Invocation Results, but when I search the Operation Id in Application Insights I still can see the three events per request shown in my question (Request, Verbose and Information).

Comment: @Victor, please see the updated section in the post, you can use another way to achieve it.

Comment: @Victor, if you still have any issues about this, please let me know:).

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried whitelisting each function and it worked in the sense that not-whitelisted functions don't show in the App Insights log, but also kills the 3 (useful) events in whitelisted functions that are injected by Azure Functions such as the Request event, and the "Request succesfully matched..." and "Executing HttpStatusCodeResult...". If you have an idea how to keep those events in whitelisted functions, please add it to the answer, otherwise let me know and I will accept this answer and award the bounty.

Comment: @Victor, I'll take a research about what you mentioned, and let you know later.

Comment: @Victor, I just contacted with the support team. Those logs like "Request succesfully matched..." and "Executing HttpStatusCodeResult..." are controlled by function host, not by each function instance. And in host.json, if set the default to None, it will stop these kinds of logs, it's an expected behavior. And no other ways to achieve that.

Comment: Thank you Ivan for helping me with this. May I ask you how did you contact the support team? I tried via the support system in Azure but I am still waiting for an answer (for 2 weeks)

Comment: @Victor, I submitted the issue to them via azure portal as per [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). And if you would like to know the details, I can provide you the email of this issue from support team.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it is required by you, but you are also able to specify this as configuration to your function app.

You need to rewrite the keys according to [the spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#override-hostjson-values)

For me it worked to add a configuration key called: `"AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__Function.FUNCTIONNAME": "Error"`

Answer (score -2):

You can delete the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` in `Application Settings` on Azure Portal.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. As I said in a comment, I am looking to disable or reduce telemetry sent from just one function and not all the functions in the application.

Comment: @Victor Hi, what the doc says is 'Controls the logging behaviors of the function app, including Application Insights.'. And it only has such a small section, I think I should have read it right. Where did you come up with the documentation stating that you can set a single function? Please note that function app is not equal to a single function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging Is this where you say?

Comment: "Version 2.x follows the ASP.NET Core layout for log category filtering. **This lets you filter logging for specific functions.**"